Do features derived from an exploratory data analysis lead to inaccurate K-fold cross validation?
I'm a little confused about the interplay of exploratory data analysis, feature engineering and feature selection using k-fold cross validation. I would much appreciate it if someone could give me some clarity.
To be more specific, I'm wondering about the case where I try to find an appropriate linear regression model, using an exploratory data analysis.
Say I have a sample of size n, each observation consisting of k variables. As a first step, I would set aside a test set for final model evaluation. Then, to understand the relations between my response and the other recorded variables, I would for example look at the correlations, plot the data to see if there are potentially any non-linear relations. I would also think about possible interactions. I would then create different features (polynomial, square root, interactions, etc.) depending on my previous observations. To see if these added features actually improve the model compared to a baseline, I would then like to perform k-fold cross validation, on the same data used for the exploratory data analysis (i.e. all observations except for those previously set aside for final model evaluation). However, I am wondering if this approach is flawed, as I did the feature engineering based on my observations which already included the full data used for k-fold cross validation, i.e. also the folds that are left out during each step. Doesn't this lead to data leakage, as I'm doing a similar mistake like if I would when performing feature engineering on my whole data set, i.e. does this generally lead to a model that results in good k-fold cross validation results, but poor results on the test data? If so, what would be the proper way to check if my engineered features are indeed relevant? Setting aside an additional validation set? Many thanks!
